# What's the best way to remove the background of an image in iOS?

Tags: ios, image-processing

I want to remove the background of an image (UIImage) and expect it to work like in the video below.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ebGoXV4_yU

I tried using ImageMagick and OpenCV but the results are not quite impressive.

What's the best approach ?

Comment: may be you can try out this as well.  http://pixlr.com/editor/

Comment: @Armaan - I'm creating an iPhone application and I want a feature in my application which should work as in the Youtube video. Hope that explains better!

Comment: sorry bro, i thought you needed editor for your images.

Comment: Not sure if you can get sample code for this or not, but best way is to write a custom algorithm like this 1) Detect color at point of click 2) check all surrounding 8 pixels for ecludian distance in terms of RGB color and if its less than threshold, include them, 3) Algo has to be recursive to keep getting all pixels till it finds them.. Basically its image processing domain..

Comment: I guess what you are mentioning is the FloodFill algorithm with tolerance (Ecludian distance). I tried that both using OpenCV and ImageMagick and the result you can here  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dl--INcvd6Q It is in no-way as good as the PhotoWizard implementation.

Comment: I played around with PhotoWizard a little more and understood that even if you tap on a transparent pixel, it will still remove part of the background. So it's clearly not based on detecting the color at the tap position and changing the surrounding pixels. I will post a video of that shortly..

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmilxKyCbZc